# Firebase load data onCreate()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to load a dataset oncreate().

Since the data will not change, I use the one time loader:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
            }
    });
    String name = currentUser.getName();
    ....
}
```

But the data is not available, the getName function is called on a null object.

How can I get the data onCreate()?

Comment: could you post mDatabase intializer?

Comment: you should be looking for the name inside the listener `onDataChange` since it will be an async call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Firebase uses an asynchronous listeners to a database reference, and you set `name` variable with null `currentUser`.

Try to declare the name var as final and before the listener, and set his value inside the firebase callback.

**Update:**
an example how to implement and use an "override" function:

```
final String name;
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            name = currentUser.getName();

            fooFunc(name); // calling a function with data
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "error:", databaseError.toException());
        }
});

@Override
public void fooFunc(String name) {
    // name != null, when called from the the callback
    // dont forget to check it
}
```

Comment: Jup that works :) But I have another issue: I also have a method `onMapReady(GoogleMap map)` which is fired earlier. And in this function I need some data from the `onDataChange`. How can I do this?

Comment: You can call that function inside the callback too, after retrieve the wished data.

Comment: But is a @Override function. Can I move it inside of onCreate?

Comment: Why do you want to move the Override implementation inside onCreate? check my update please.

Comment: onMapReady is called by the system. I'm not calling this function anywhere

Comment: Oh, i understand better now, sorry. Then you should retrieve the data before the current activity, or implement the `onMapReady` to work only if the data is not null, and call this function again when you retrieved the data. I'll try to think of a better solution for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115588/discussion-between-ami-hollander-and-zoker).